# ASP.NET MVC Core: Dependancy Injection не в контроллере

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

А как я могу передать сервисы из Dependancy Injection которые зарегестрированы в startup.cs в приложении ASP.NET MVC Core в классы отличные от класса контроллера?

Правильно ли я понял что их туда надо вручную прокидывать, так как статические методы и переменные это старая идеология, и она уже не поддерживается в ASP.NET MVC Core и IoC как раз и призван что бы её заменить?

**UPDATED:**
Делаю инициализатор базы данных, и думаю откуда в нём взять ApplicationDbContext и UserManager

```
public static class DbInitializer
    {

        public static async void Initialize(ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            if(db.Users.Count() == 0 && db.Roles.Count() == 0)
            {
                ApplicationUser user1 = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = "Admin",
                    Age = 30
                };
                await userManager.CreateAsync(user1,"password");

              //...
            }
        } 
    }
```

Класс sturtup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
           //...

            DbInitializer.Initialize(db, userManager, roleManager);
        }
```

Пока делаю вот так, но думаю может можно как-то сразу из `DbInitializer` получить необходимые сервисы.

Comment: добавь пример кода. не совсем понятно что ты имеешь ввиду

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Answer (score 0):

вроде ваш код можно назвать правильный реализаций но  этот код можно улучшить.
жесткий зависимость в коде это зло
я бы реализовал вот так :
 
если нет админа то редирект на регистрацию или throw "ApplicationNotConfiguredException" и указать в документации что нужно создать пользователя в базе. 
но не в этом суть
такие классы будет нужен в контексте контроллера.
вы , используйте абстрактные типы (intefaces,abstract classes) и имейте в виду что канче канчов будете вызывать эти классы в контроллере.суть заключается в том что контроллер должен вызывать ваши дополнительные функциональные классы и господь благословил вас давая 3 способа внедрения зависимости.
потому что контроллер это основной building block вашей приложений.
без него нет жизни для других классов
если это не так для вас тогда вы имеете в виду не MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете зарегистрировать dbcontext используя как раз встроенные средства для di. Для этого в секции ConfigureServices вашего startup.cs добавьте

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(...)
```

Далее, вы можете передать этот контекст как аргумент конструктора класса (это по сути разновидность способа наследования названная аггрегацией). Работает следующим образом

```
public class SomeClass
{
  ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext;
  public SomeClass(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
  {
     this.applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
  }
}
```

Затем используйте свой контекст.

Comment: вот еще пример https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio от майрософта, вроде очень идентичен вашему.